# Convert docx file from Gmail to HTML

Tags: java, android, html, gmail, docx

I am making an Android application which reads from HTML and then saves the text to a TextView etc.

I want to download an attached docx-file from an email-account, and then convert it into a HTML file and finally read the text from it. Why i want to convert it is because the application is already reading from HTML-sites.

Is this Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use tm-extractors (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.textmining/tm-extractors), and fall back to the commercial Aspose (http://www.aspose.com/). Both have native Java APIs.